# MYSQL filling row Blanks with values from joined table - random spaces

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with rows of main images and another with alternate images.

main_table...

```
id      |    image1  |    image2  |    image3   |   image4   |  image5  |
__________________________________________________________________________

3498    | main-1.jpg | main-2.jpg |  NULL       |  NULL      |  NULL
3476    | main-1.jpg | main-2.jpg |  NULL       |  NULL      |  NULL 
3034    | main-1.jpg | NULL       |  NULL       |  NULL      |  NULL
3698    | main-1.jpg | main-2.jpg |  main-3.jpg |  NULL      |  NULL
```

alt_images_table........

```
id      |    alt_image1  |    alt_image2  |  alt_image3
_________________________________________________________________________

3498    | alt-1.jpg      | alt-2.jpg      |  alt-3.jpg
3476    | alt-1.jpg      | alt-2.jpg      |  NULL
3034    | alt-1.jpg      | NULL           |  NULL
3698    | alt-1.jpg      | alt-2.jpg      |  alt-3.jpg
```

These two tables are joined by the id. What is the best way to fill the NULLs in the main_table with the alt images from the alt_images_table? I thought of maybe doing a count fields in row and then a case to have the images fill at the next number field.

```
SET image3=
CASE
WHEN image1 is not NULL and image2 IS NOT NULL THEN alt_image1......etc.....etc....
END
```

But this will be  lot of code to set up. I'm just not sure if there is a better way. So far everything i am thinking of seems to be over the top in code. There are never blanks in between main images. The number of them vary in each row as the example shows.

Thanks

Comment: To efficiently solve this requires looping over arrays so it would probably be much simpler to do in your application framework.

Comment: Do you consider redesigning database structure? It is better to have one table with rows:
image_id (autoincrement), primary;
id;
type (enum ('main', 'alt'));
order (1,2,3,4,5);
filename.

Comment: That can be something to consider in the future. Thank you......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `null` values are all at the end, you can express the logic using `case`:

```
update maintable m join
       alt_images ai
       on m.id = ai.id
    set m.image1 = coalesce(m.image1, a.alt_image1),
        m.image2 = (case when m.image1 is null then a.alt_image2
                         when m.image2 is null then a.alt_image1
                         else m.image2
                    end),
        m.image3 = (case when m.image1 is null then a.alt_image3
                         when m.image2 is null then a.alt_image2
                         when m.image3 is null then a.alt_image1
                         else m.image3
                    end),
        m.image4 = (case when m.image1 is null then a.alt_image4
                         when m.image2 is null then a.alt_image3
                         when m.image3 is null then a.alt_image2
                         when m.image4 is null then a.alt_image1
                         else m.image4
                    end),
        m.image4 = (case when m.image1 is null then a.alt_image5
                         when m.image2 is null then a.alt_image4
                         when m.image3 is null then a.alt_image3
                         when m.image4 is null then a.alt_image2
                         when m.image5 is null then a.alt_image1
                         else m.image5
                    end);
```

I realize that `alt_images` doesn't have as many images as `maintable`.  However, I've left in the references so the logic is clearer.

Comment: This works like a charm! I figured there wasn't a shortcut. Thank you for showing me this and also teaching me more about coalesce.......